# How does Spring start this app?

Tags: java, spring, jms, hornetq

I'm parsing through some inherited code of a Java app that is deployed as a WAR file in JBOSS, and uses Spring, JMS, and HornetQ. I'm trying to figure out, for lack of a better phrase, what makes the app "go". Most of the Spring examples I've seen include an application with a main() method, which imperatively acts on the beans provided by the Spring context in some way. This application has no main(). As far as I can tell, this is what's happening:

The WAR file's web.xml uses a listener to launch Spring when the application starts in JBOSS, and passes it a config file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Spring then processes the application-context.xml file, which includes this snippet:

```
<bean id="jmsContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="appListenerProxy" />
```

Through a couple more references in the application-context.xml, the "appListenerProxy" ultimately refers to a class in the application that implements SessionAwareMessageListener, which responds to messages on a queue.

The part that's tripping me up is that I don't see any kind of code to get the jmsContainer bean and do something with it. Is that a well-defined ID, such that the Spring framework is looking for it? And if so, is that documented somewhere (along with other IDs the framework might be looking for)? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html seemed to be the closest I found, but it doesn't really specify whether that ID is just in the examples by convention, or if it's a meaningful string.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Spring are you working with? Also, without seeing the code in question I don't think this can be answered definitively. But, since Spring is a [DI framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) I think it's safe to assume that the bean is injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containers in spring are part of the framework core. The Framework will scan all the containers that implement a certain container interface, and initialize them.

This also relies on the Inversion of Control (IoC) principle.

For more information on IoC Container, check this page:
[IoC Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

Comment: I think this is more or less what I was looking for. It looks like the InitializingBean interface is the key part I was missing - the framework initializes those after instantiating them, and with the autoStartup property, that results in the container starting to respond to messages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` bean, its frame work part.

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` bean establish JMS session with your JMS destination on application startup. When message are received in your destination it invokes the `messageListener` `onMessage` method- in your case `appListenerProxy` bean.

read [here](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/using-spring-to-receive-jms-messages.html).